# Combine Dates with Homerun Data from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, highcharts

The idea is to take "Dates" and "homeruns" from the .json. Combine matching Dates together and add up the homeruns. Currently I'm able to display the Dates combined together with matching dates but the Homeruns don't add up, just stack next to each other. For example .... Date: "1985", Hits: "3", Homeruns: "101"}
Eventually I want to all take the dates with combined homeruns and display it in highcharts in a barchart (but i'll figure that out later).

**chart.json**

```
[{"Date": "1903", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1903", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1904", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1904", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1904", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1905", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1907", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1907", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1909", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1909", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1909", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1909", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1910", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1910", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1910", "Hits": "?", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1911", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1912", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1914", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1915", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1916", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1916", "Hits": "?", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1917", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1918", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1918", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1918", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1918", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1919", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1919", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1919", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1920", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1922", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1922", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1931", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1934", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1935", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1936", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "2"}, {"Date": "1937", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1937", "Hits": "2", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1940", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1942", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1946", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1948", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1949", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1949", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1950", "Hits": "1", "Homeruns": "0"}, {"Date": "1951", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1951", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1951", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1951", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1952", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1952", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1954", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1954", "Hits": "2", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1955", "Hits": "0", "Homeruns": "1"}, {"Date": "1956", "Hits": "2", "Homeruns": "1"}]
```

**JS**

```
function chartPage()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'chart.json',
                data:
                {},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var stringy = JSON.stringify(data);
                    var objects = $.parseJSON(stringy);
                    var categories = new Array();
                    var groupedObjects = new Array();
                    var i = 0;
                    _.each(objects, function(obj)
                    {
                        var existingObj;
                        if ($.inArray(obj.Date, categories) >= 0)
                        {
                            existingObj = _.find(objects, function(o)
                            {
                                return o.Date === obj.Date;
                            });
                            existingObj["Homeruns"] += obj["Homeruns"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            groupedObjects[i] = obj;
                            categories[i] = obj.Date;
                            i++;
                        }
                    });
                    groupedObjects = _.sortBy(groupedObjects, function(obj)
                    {
                        return obj["Homeruns"];
                    }).reverse();
                    // print results for testing
                    _.each(groupedObjects, function(obj)
                    {
                        var output = '';
                        _.each(obj, function(val, key)
                        {
                            output += key + ': ' + val + '<br>';
                        });
                        output += '<br>';
                        $('#results').append(output);
                        console.log(output);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homeruns don't add up most probably because you are adding strings. Anyway, I would use simpler solution:

```
_.each(data, function (item) {
  // if Date doesn't exist, create empty placeholder:
  if (!tempHomeruns[item.Date]) {
    tempHomeruns[item.Date] = 0;
  }
  // sum Homeruns
  tempHomeruns[item.Date] += parseInt(item.Homeruns, 10);
});

// create Highcharts required format:
_.each(tempHomeruns, function(item, key) {
  homeruns.push({
    name: key,
    y: item
  });
});
```

And Highcharts code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: [{
    data: homeruns
  }]
});
```

And here is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nd4rvLvs/ (and example with both, Hits and Homeruns: http://jsfiddle.net/nd4rvLvs/1/ ;) )

Comment: holy cow. That's so much easier. Wow! Thank you!